# How to find records whose some field value are all zero in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I have lots of sensors, every sensor report a data every few seconds.

I need to find out the sensors whose data are all zero.

Furthurmore, I need to caculate the zero data ratio for every sensor.

Can any query can do this?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

The records are like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61353065746e5e18a1d7c4ca"),
    "sensor" : "SN54",
    "category" : "w",
    "data" : "7065",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-09-06T05:02:29.308+08:00")
},

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("61353065746e5e18a1d7c4c9"),
    "sensor" : "SN68",
    "category" : "w",
    "data" : "0",
    "time" : ISODate("2021-09-06T05:02:29.308+08:00")
},
```

Comment: can you add sample data? and expected out data after the query if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query (if data was in array (we dont need it here after the question update))

- filter to keep the zero only, divides with all array size, and multiply with 100
- if you want to get all zero, add a match where `percentage=100`

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BOMuEmUVXQY)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "percentage": {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$data",
                  []
                ]
              },
              0,
              {
                "$divide": [
                  {
                    "$size": {
                      "$filter": {
                        "input": "$data",
                        "as": "d",
                        "cond": {
                          "$eq": [
                            "$$d",
                            0
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "$size": "$data"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

---

**Edit1** (for data that are not inside array)

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B4yKFeyWSDd)

```js
aggregate(
[ {
  "$group" : {
    "_id" : "$sensor",
    "nzero" : {
      "$sum" : {
        "$cond" : [ {
          "$eq" : [ "$data", "0" ]
        }, 1, 0 ]
      }
    },
    "count" : {
      "$sum" : 1
    }
  }
}, {
  "$set" : {
    "sensor" : "$_id"
  }
}, {
  "$project" : {
    "_id" : 0
  }
}, {
  "$project" : {
    "sensor" : 1,
    "percentage" : {
      "$multiply" : [ {
        "$divide" : [ "$nzero", "$count" ]
      }, 100 ]
    }
  }
} ]
)
```

Comment: Sorry, please see the data sample, the data field is not array

Comment: its ok , check the update, if you want you can add other accumulators also like `$avg` average etc